# What do you call the individual enclosed defecating areas in toilets?

Tags: word-choice, image-identification

[image: picture of three (turkish style) toilets separated by dividers]

For example, in the picture above, there are three of them.

How should I refer to them?

As in a sentence like:

> I excused myself and went to the toilet, but all of the [...] were occupied.

Comment: These are called _stalls_. This also seems like more of an ELL question than an ELU question.

Comment: @J.R. Sorry, can we do a migration?

Comment: Perhaps a mod can migrate it. Or maybe you could delete it here and ask it over there. Or maybe you could just keep that idea in mind for next time. (But don't leave it open here and re-ask it over there.)

Comment: I'm not an expert because in Europe they are almost not used, but, sometimes, I heard they called 'turk toilet' or 'squatty potty'. Out of curiousity, are they used in your country?

Comment: @J.R. Separated by a common language:  *Why is it that the (BrE) **cubicles** in American (BrE) **public toilets** never go all the way to the floor or the ceiling ...*; *"There's no paper in the second (AmE) **stall**"* ... *And so I defensively asked "What would you call it then?"  Ta-da! I give you **cubicle**.* http://separatedbyacommonlanguage.blogspot.in/2010/04/stalls-and-cubicles.html

Comment: @Kris - I'm not surprised there's more than one name for that place where we do our "duty". As a matter of fact, I'd be rather surprised to find the opposite – that the same term is used in all contexts, in every nation of every continent. Had the question mentioned that specifically (i.e., something like, "I know these are called _stalls_ in the U.S., but are they more commonly known by another term in other parts of the world?"), then I might have cast an upvote instead of suggesting another exchange.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are called *stalls*. Wikipedia shows the definition of "stall" as

> a small enclosure of some kind, usually less enclosed than a room.

and gives these examples:

- In a cathedral, the stalls are the seats built into the quire (or choir) in the eastern end of the structure.
- In a theatre or concert hall auditorium, the stalls, also referred to as orchestra seats, are the seats on the ground floor directly in front of the stage.
- In a public washroom, multiple toilets are separated into stalls for privacy.
- In the United Kingdom the bake sale is known as a cake stall.
  a high-backed booth at a restaurant
- A shower stall

Answer (score 6):

The individual areas are called *[cubicles](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cubicle)* (BrE).

Comment: Wait, why exactly was this downvoted? I myself refer to the individual partitions as 'stalls' or 'cubicles'.

Comment: I can imagine someone downvoting this because I myself would never have figured anyone would call it this. 'Stall' is the only word I know for this, and 'cubicle' refers _only_ to a desk enclosure at an office... in American English. Possibly 'cubicle' is what is used in other varieties of English (british? Aussie? etc?)

Comment: +1 from me! But it might be a good idea to edit your answer and mention that *cubicle* is BrE. The dictionary reference doesn't mention anything about toilets either.

Comment: I've never called it a stall in my life, in AuE is it consistently "*cubicle*".  We understand "*stall*", though.

Comment: Jasper, you're right. They are called cubicles in the UK.

Comment: Should someone downvote Mr. Shiny and New 安宇 for his US-orientated (oops, oriented) answer?

Comment: Hmmm...it seems among the commenters I'm unique in using 'stall' and 'cubicle' interchangeably. I guess that comes with being from the Anglophone Caribbean: we inherited our English from Britain, but we can't escape U.S. influence.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Hey! My answer is Canadian-orientated! ;)

Comment: @ Mr. Shiny and New 安宇 Looks like N American mischief to me.

Comment: "Stalls" looks to have started out as US American but it's long been understood in British English, too. I have the impression that in the UK, "stalls" would be more common in technical language, as with architects or facilities managers. "Cubicles" is still more lady-like… and there's also the much less polite "traps" stemming from the way the picture above resembles the starting traps at a greyhound stadium.