# Origin of expression "orchestra seat"

Tags: phrase-origin

Orchestra seats are mentioned in [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/143651/50782) but why are seats closest to the orchestra (or stage) called "orchestra seats"?  They are certainly not *in* the orchestra.  What is the history/origin of such an expression?

Comment: @user66974 : the expression may seem intuitive but this may be due to the fact that we are accustomed to its common use.  If you speak any languages other than English, you can check whether a literal translation makes sense there.

Comment: True.  I mentioned that in my *question*.  But this does  not answer the question of history/origin.

Comment: Just to add a wild speculation: perhaps at some point informal concert halls were simpler than the version we have today, and actually had spectators sitting in the space allotted to the orchestra.  I have no evidence for such a guess, though.  @user66974

Comment: This seems like asking why are window seats next to the window?

Comment: As emerges clearly from Graffito's answer, the reason they are called "orchestra seats" is *not* because they are next to the orchestra.  Rather, they are *in* the space that used to be called the *orchestra* (literally, "dancing space").  Today that space contains spectators instead of dancers and singers. @StuartF

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When referring to the architecture of Greek theater, the "orchestra" corresponds to the part of the theater located between the scene and stone tiered seating.

[image]
[source](https://uhsband.com/musichistory/antiquity/greekdrama.php)

The location of the *orchestra* corresponds to "the seats on the ground floor directly in front of the stage" where you find orchestra seats in modern theaters .

**edit:**
The orchestra (literally, "dancing space") was a level space where the chorus would dance, sing, and interact with the actors who were on the stage near the skene.
As it is the place for singers and chorus, it is probably (*to be confirmed*) the origin of the term "orchestra" in the sense of musical group. Note that the first significant orchestra was [Louis XIV 24 Violin-Family Instruments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Vingt-quatre_Violons_du_Roi)

Comment: Does the original meaning of "orchestra" in Greek correspond to the meaning we have today?  In other words, was there actually a group of musicians in the space of the purple circle in your illustration?

Comment: The link to Louis 14 is broken.

Comment: "Note that the first significant orchestra was..." Music for large instrumental ensembles existed before that.

Comment: @phoog . [Quote from this source](https://www.naxos.com/CatalogueDetail/?id=8.573868) : The Italian-born violinist and dancer Jean-Baptiste Lully revolutionised music at the French court in the 17th century , not only did he transform ballet entertainments into a spectacular new genre, the tragédie lyrique, but he set new standards in orchestral playing—with him the ‘modern’ orchestra was born.

Answer (score -2):

"orchestra seats" takes the form of {noun1 + noun2} with noun1 being attributive.

noun1 + noun2 is understood as "The noun2 that is/are contextually associated with noun1".

The contextual association is the proximity.

**Edit to add:**

The Greek origins of the word "orchestra" are interesting but of only doubtful use in explaining why "orchestra seats" are so called.

"Orchestra" in this sense given by Graffito is historical only.

The term "Orchestra seat(s)" did not appear in English until c. 1800

Google Ngram [orchestra seat,orchestra seats](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=orchestra%20seat%2Corchestra%20seats&year_start=1700&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

> **History of the Colored Race in America - Page 382 William T. Alexander · 1800**
>
> *One man sprang from an orchestra seat upon the stage and shouted to " Stop him!*

By this time "orchestra" was well established  in its meaning of "an ensemble of musicians"

It is clear from OED

> 2.b.(a) The part of a theatre, opera house, or other public building where the musicians perform; (b) a building or structure for a band of musicians; a bandstand (now rare).
>
> 1724 *Orchestra, is that Part of the Theater, where the Musicians sit with their Instruments to perform.* Short Explication of Foreign Words Musick Books

that in 1724, "orchestra" was considered a foreign word and did not refer to the Greek concept of "orchestra".

Comment: As emerges clearly from Graffito's answer, the reason they are called "orchestra seats" is not because they are located in the "proximity" of the orchestra as you claim.  Rather, they are in the space that used to be called the orchestra (literally, "dancing space"). Today that space contains spectators instead of dancers and singers.

Comment: @MikhailKatz May I suggest that you read the question? **"but why are seats closest to the orchestra (or stage) called "orchestra seats"? They are certainly not in the orchestra."** This question presupposes the current meaning of "orchestra" - not the Greek version. The Greek origins are of little use. See the addition to my answer.

Comment: Greybeard, indeed I originally assumed that the meaning of *orchestra* in the expression is similar to the current meaning of the term *orchestra*.  It turns out that it is not, which solves the puzzle of the expression.  Incidentally, I did not downvote.